# Upgrading GWT, Bootstrap and GWT-Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, gwt, gwt-bootstrap

Currently I am using GWT 2.5.1 and Bootstrap 2.3.2 versions. And also I am using GWTBootstrap (com.github.gwtbootstrap.Bootstrap) 2.2.1.0 version.
I need to upgrade GWT to 2.6 ,Bootstrap to 3.1 and GWTBootstrap to 2.3.2.0-Snapshot versions. These upgradations are latest versions.

Will this upgradation works fine without any issues???

I have a question on this because GWTBootstrap  latest version is 2.x and bootstrap version is 3.x, will they be compatible??
Can I able to add any latest bootstrap styles to GWTBootstrap components?? 
Will the added bootstrap styles overrides the existing styles of gwt-bootstrap wigets??
Will it work?? 
Please suggest any ideas..

Answer (score 3):

Bootstrap 3 is a major change from 2
So no. The styles won't be compatible.

Check out gwt for bootstrap3
https://github.com/gwtbootstrap3/gwtbootstrap3

I didn't try it yet. So I can report anything of how it works.